# Undefined references while linking test generated by CMake

Tags: cmake, googletest

My `CMakeList.txt` has the following problematic section:

```
add_executable(esh_test tests/libtest.c esh.c tests/esh_test.cpp)
add_dependencies(esh_test esh)
target_link_libraries(esh_test
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/esh-grammar.o
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libesh.a
        l dl readline curses libgtest gtest_main)
```

Problematic because it won't link properly:

```
$> cmake ./; make
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: src/
[  0%] Built target lexpar
[  0%] Built target libesh
[ 14%] Built target esh
[ 71%] Built target gtest
[ 78%] Linking CXX executable esh_test
CMakeFiles/esh_test.dir/esh_test.cpp.o: In function `testcase_test_test_Test::TestBody()':
esh_test.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `mkredir()'
esh_test.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `esh_usage(char*)'
esh_test.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `redir_restore_streams(redir*)'
esh_test.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `fd_grep_regex(int, char*)'
esh_test.cpp:(.text+0x107): undefined reference to `redir_cleanup(redir*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The `link.txt` for this module is:

```
/usr/bin/c++ -std=c++11 CMakeFiles/esh_test.dir/esh_test.cpp.o CMakeFiles/esh_test.dir/libtest.c.o CMakeFiles/esh_test.dir/esh.c.o -o esh_test -rdynamic ../esh-grammar.o ../libesh.a -ll -ldl -lreadline -lcurses gtest/src/gtest-build/libgtest.a -lgtest_main -lpthread
```

Which seems like it would link in the missing functions, declared in `libtest.h` and defined in `libtest.c`.

This is my first CMake project, so I'm a little lost. What's going on here?

Comment: Can you give a bit more info?  Specifically, what are the targets `libesh`, and `esh` and do all the undefined references definitely belong in libtest.c/.h (since e.g. `esh_usage(char*)` looks like it could belong in `libesh` or `esh`).  Probably best if you can show the whole CMakeLists.txt if it's not huge.

Comment: The problem at hand aside (for which we'd need more info, as Fraser pointed out), linking in `*.o` and `*.a` files from within `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` doesn't look good to me. Object files and libraries aren't supposed to reside there...

Comment: If all the missing functions reside in `libtest.c`, they'd be compiled into `esh_test` directly as per your `add_executable()` statement. The linker complaining means they are *not* defined in `libtest.c`. Check your assumptions.